# Why my php page is not sending mail

Tags: php, html, email

When I reload the page a link is shown **send mail** but when I click this link ,it doesnt redirect to send mail, whats wrong with my code?

```
<?php
echo '<a href="//mailto:me@example.com?Subject=We are going to ibiza" target="_top">Emil now</a>';
?>
```

please help, thanks!

Comment: Remove the `//`in your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:
http://de.selfhtml.org/html/verweise/email.htm

I think you just Need to remove the two // in the link

Answer (score 1):

You are adding // before the **mailto** this is the main problem with your coding!>**I have improved your code bellow, hope this helps!**

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mailto:me@example.com?Subject=We+are+going+to+ ibiza" target="_top">Emil now</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two slashed before "mailto"

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mailto:me@example.com?Subject=We are going to ibiza" target="_top">Emil now</a>';
?>
```